# One-liner to fetch data in a loop / iterator and store into a variable

Tags: php, iterator

Is there some magic one-liner to get this data ?

```
while ($res->next())
{
    $this->data['DwellingUnit'][] = $res->row;
}
```

Not `while ($res->next()) $this->data['DwellingUnit'][] = $res->row;`

Comment: What is `$res` when you do a var_dump()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume [`iterator_to_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php) can be used with `array_column`:

```
$this->data['DwellingUnit'] = array_column(
    iterator_to_array($res),
    'row'
);
```

As [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php#refsect1-function.array-column-changelog) can extract values from array of objects too, but since **php7**.

As a con: here're **two** loops - one over iterator to get an array, second is over array to extract `row` property.

Comment: I forgot whether I had made `array_column` work for iterators in particular, need to check the source again :)

Comment: Update: I guess I didn't :(

Comment: I suppose typehint in a manual would be `iterable` or similar then)